# FacesContext in a @WebListener

Tags: jsf-2.2, servletcontextlistener, facescontext

I need build some jsf urls in a `@WebListener`.

I thought I could use a snippet of code like this one

```
    final FacesContext currentInstance = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    final String actionURL = currentInstance.getApplication().getViewHandler()
            .getActionURL(currentInstance, viewId);
```

because the javadoc of the `.getCurrentInstance()` asserts it can be "[...] called during application initialization or shutdown" but it doesn't work because it returns null.

Do I miss somenthing? Any other way to build a url given the viewId?

Thanks

Comment: What is the real problem for which you think this might be a solution?

Comment: This is what I need. At the start of the context I need to generate some urls for another webapp (completely unaware of jsf, but this shouldn't be relevenat) in a configuration agnostic manner. I know I could do something like`servletContext.getContextPath() + "/file.xthml"` but I _hope_ there is a better way.

Comment: Why a 'better' way? What is wrong with the way you do it? Maybe explain a little more

Comment: I don't want to deal with facelets extensions and mappings and let jsf do the job. Quite straightforward

Comment: Describe how and where you want/need this viewId to be presented to the other webapp.... That is what your real 'problem' is, you seem to be 'stuck' in this solution.... FacesContext current instance is available after the FacesServlet is reached, not before (as can be read in other posts). So that is why it is null. But what for you is quite straight forward is for me totally blurry, but that might be cause by my limited vision/view/knowledge/... Maybe others can help out....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` method *does* return a valid `facesContext` instance between the linstener (`com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener` in my case) initialization and the first run of the FacesServlet, in which the `facesContext` set up by the listener is released.
My problem was I was letting Wildfly add the listener and it was added just after mine. Forcing its loading in the `web-fragment.xml`/`web.xml`

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.company.project.somepackages.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

let my listener have the context initialized.

That code above *however* didn't work because the viewHandler when tries to resolve the contextPath uses the `externalContext.getRequestContextPath()` method, that obviously returns `null`, and not the `externalContext.getApplicationContextPath()` that could return the correct value.